# C: Returning D as output why?

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *s="hello world";
    printf("%c\n",s);
}
```

I have written a small code in C. In last statement of this code I'm using `%c` format-specifier in `printf()` function and assigning pointer named `s` in it. It is giving me `D` as output. Does it is returning garbage value or does my code automatically assigning ASCII value in it or something else?

When I add `s+1` it return `E` and `s+2` return `F` and so on. Can anyone clarify me?

Comment: Because strings are printed with `%s`, as foretold in the first chapter of your favourite, beginner level C programming book. Your code invokes an undefined behavior bug meaning anything can happen. Probably the compiler attempts to print the first byte of the _address_ to `s` as a character.

Comment: Check the data types....

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh thank you.

Answer (score 7):

`%c` prints a `char`, not a string. Since your variable `s` is not a `char`, but rather a pointer to a `char`, `printf` interprets the address to your string as a character. You probably want to use one of the snippets:

```c
printf("%c\n", s[0]); // print the first character in your string
printf("%s\n", s); // print the whole string
```

Comment: I would argue that `s[0]` would better fit as `*s` in communicating the intention of the code

Comment: That is a great suggestion @Ackdari, I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

regarding:

```
printf("%c\n",s);
```

results in the compiler output:

```
*untitled2.c:5:14: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ *[-Wformat=]*
```

When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  Suggest:

```
printf("%s\n",s);
```

so the statement is using the correct 'output format conversion' specifier to output the whole string

--OR--

to output a single character suggest:

```
printf( "%c\n", s[0] );
```

to output only the first character `h`

Answer (score 1):

On considering how you are doing in this code lets just say, yes you are getting garbage values when you are giving `s`/`s+1`/`s+2`... in `printf()`. That's just because of your format specifier`%c`(type is `char`) is being mismatched with `s`( type is string). The fix is change the latter to type `char` and your problems will be fixed.

You don't need to worry about where this value is coming from as, at the end of the day it's a garbage value and will be different for different for different people using the code. And there is no possible usage for it as far as I can see.

Try the following code below and your code will work fine:

```
    char *s="hello world";
    printf("%c\n",*s);
```

or

```
    char *s="hello world";
    printf("%c\n",s[0]);
```

These answers are discussed in answers and comments above.But you should also try this,

```
    char s[]="hello world";
    printf("%c\n",s[0]);
```

Because, although pointers are present in C, swift,etc. They are discouraged because they present major issues for memory safety and garbage collection.

Edit: Stackoverflow fam need some upvotes at the current state i can't even comment. (Only if 
i am right)

Comment: In C there is no type `String`. `char *` is indeed the correct way to declare a string in C.

Comment: @Ashish Kumar thank you.One more question does String s="hi" will work in C.as you posted in your answer.does i need to import any library or something for this to work in C.

Comment: @MartinFink  char array -> 'char name []' is the right way to declare a string in C. Look here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strings-in-c-2/  you can find difference here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c/

Comment: @ManinderSingh my bad sorry ... i program in java hence string came up while typing... any ways i tried to write a generalized answer for you. But i corrected it now for you. Good Day

Comment: @AshishKumar ok.but MartinFink is also right.You can also define string like this in C. char *x="hi"; This is the best way to define string in C.The reason behind it because there is no memory wastage.

Comment: Unless you are going to just print the string, this method is useless. Because you are creating pointer variable to string , making direct manipulation impossible. Try 'x[1]= 'Y' ' for the example you gave @ManinderSingh