# Why single digit numbers are appended with "D" (in C output)?

Tags: c, terminal, output, eof, kernighan-and-ritchie

Why single digit numbers are appended with "D" (in C output)?

The following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c = 0;

    printf("%d\n", c); 

    return 0;
}
```

once compiled & ran, outputs `0`, as I would expect it to.

Though, this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c = 0;

    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        ++c;
    }

    printf("%d\n", c); 

    return 0;
}
```

once compiled & ran, after triggering `EOF` right away -- outputs `0D` for some reason, though value of `c` (as far as I can see) should be absolutely the same as in the first case.

 Same happens for all the single digit numbers (i.e. `1D`, `2D`, `3D` ... `9D`), starting with `10` the appending `D` is not seen anymore.

I'd like to know:

1. Why `D` is appended to the output in the second case, but not in the first (even though `c` should hold the same value)?
2. Is it possible to avoid this `D` appending (and how, if it is)?

Comment: My ***guess*** is that the terminal writes out `^D` from the `Ctrl-D` end-of-file keyboard sequence. Then your program writes the value of `c` and a newline, which overwrites the `^` in `^D`. You probably need to check your terminal configuration to see if it's possible to disable it.

Comment: Look for `echoctl` in your output from `stty`.  It causes control characters like `^D` to be echoed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code simply cannot output a "D" for whatever reason. Not unless something really iffy happens, like a bug in the compiler or glibc. Or maybe a bitflip in memory.

The "D" is very likely due to the terminal you're using, but your code simply CANNOT output it.

Well, there is a very small chance. If you read more than `INT_MAX` characters, then the signed integer `c` will overflow, thus invoking undefined behavior. It's not likely that this would output a "D", but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

When posting the question, I thought this behaviour has something to do with cases like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61265396/c-returning-d-as-output-why), but, as it turned out, it has nothing to do with the code and is **solely terminal behaviour**.

 Suggestion by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) in a comment, is exactly right: terminal simply outputs `^D` and output of the program then overwrites `^`, but not `D`, thus for single-digit numbers output ends up being appended with `D`.

Two (or more) digit numbers simply overwrite the whole `^D`.

I was able to verify this by changing `EOF` triggering sequence to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (by `stty eof ^L`), then the output becomes `1L`, `2L`, `3L` ... `9L`.

As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) said in comment above disabling echoing of control characters (by `stty -echoctl`) would solve the issue.